# Can't get image upload to work with Flask and JQuery

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

The following code allows you to submit forms and return a variation of the text from Flask using AJAX and JQuery:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('form.html')

@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def process():

    email = request.form['email']
    name = request.form['name']

    if name and email:
        newName = name[::-1]

        return jsonify({'name' : newName})

    return jsonify({'error' : 'Missing data!'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AJAX Example</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/form.js') }}"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <br><br><br><br>
    <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="emailInput">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailInput" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="nameInput">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nameInput" placeholder="First Name">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div id="successAlert" class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div id="errorAlert" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('form').on('submit', function(event) {

        $.ajax({
            data : {
                name : $('#nameInput').val(),
                email : $('#emailInput').val()
            },
            type : 'POST',
            url : '/process'
        })
        .done(function(data) {

            if (data.error) {
                $('#errorAlert').text(data.error).show();
                $('#successAlert').hide();
            }
            else {
                $('#successAlert').text(data.name).show();
                $('#errorAlert').hide();
            }

        });

        event.preventDefault();

    });

});
```

But when I slightly modify the code to do the same thing with a uploaded file's name it doesn't work.  All I have done is changed the type of form so that it takes in files and then made it so that it reverses the filename rather than the inputted text from the previous version.  Do you know what I am doing wrong here?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('form.html')

@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def process():

    filename = request.files['file'].filename

    if filename:
        newName = filename[::-1]

        return jsonify({'name' : newName})

    return jsonify({'error' : 'Missing data!'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AJAX Example</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/form.js') }}"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <br><br><br><br>
    <form method="POST" action='/process' enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div>
          <label for="file">Choose file to upload</label>
          <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
       </form>
    <br>
    <div id="successAlert" class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div id="errorAlert" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('form').on('submit', function(event) {

        $.ajax({
            data : {
                
                file : $('#file')
            },
            type : 'POST',
            url : '/process'
        })
        .done(function(data) {

            if (data.error) {
                $('#errorAlert').text(data.error).show();
                $('#successAlert').hide();
            }
            else {
                $('#successAlert').text(data.name).show();
                $('#errorAlert').hide();
            }

        });

        event.preventDefault();

    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an object of the type FormData to serialize and transfer the data of the form it should work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').submit(function(event) {
    let formData = new FormData(event.target);
    $.ajax({
      data: formData,
      type : 'POST',
      url : '/process',
      contentType: false,
      processData: false
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      if (data.error) {
        $('#errorAlert').text(data.error).show();
        $('#successAlert').hide();
      } else {
        $('#successAlert').text(data.name).show();
        $('#errorAlert').hide();
      }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have fixed the problem - unlike the original code this simply redirects to a screen with 'JSON', 'Raw Data', and 'Headers', rather than printing out a reverse of the filename in the original page

Comment: @tewerty Sorry. Have revised my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much - that's working perfectly now!  Can I ask what difference those two lines of code make and why?

Comment: @tewerty `contentType: false` prevents the automatic setting of the content type by jQuery. `processData: false` prevents the data from being converted into a character string. This means that the settings of the FormData object are used.

Comment: Can I also ask what event.preventDefault() accomplishes here?

Comment: @tewerty It prevents the standard behavior of the form. This means that the javascript code is executed without the form being sent to the server. This is done by the ajax call. `preventDefault` is always required when the normal behavior on the event is not required. Without this command, the form would be sent and the javascript call would be prevented.

Comment: I see - thank you!